# How to change the color PageView Slider in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

I don't know what actually it called so I randomly asked a question and ignore all the grammar mistakes just give me a solution of my problem. I want to change that blue color to orange color when I slide to end page and i am a beginner in flutter so i need help...

This is my OnboardingScreen.dart file

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:secret_partner/data/data.dart';

class OnboardingScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _OnboardingScreenState createState() => _OnboardingScreenState();
}

class _OnboardingScreenState extends State<OnboardingScreen> {

  List<SliderModel> mySLides = new List<SliderModel>();
  int slideIndex = 0;
  PageController controller;

  Widget _buildPageIndicator(bool isCurrentPage){
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 2.0),
      height: isCurrentPage ? 10.0 : 6.0,
      width: isCurrentPage ? 10.0 : 6.0,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: isCurrentPage ? Colors.grey : Colors.grey[300],
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    mySLides = getSlides();
    controller = new PageController();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: [const Color(0xFF9E9E9E), const Color(0xFFE0E0E0)])),
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 50,
          child: PageView(
            controller: controller,
            onPageChanged: (index) {
              setState(() {
                slideIndex = index;
              });
            },
            children: <Widget>[
              SlideTile(
                imagePath: mySLides[0].getImageAssetPath(),
                title: mySLides[0].getTitle(),
                desc: mySLides[0].getDesc(),
              ),
              SlideTile(
                imagePath: mySLides[1].getImageAssetPath(),
                title: mySLides[1].getTitle(),
                desc: mySLides[1].getDesc(),
              ),
              SlideTile(
                imagePath: mySLides[2].getImageAssetPath(),
                title: mySLides[2].getTitle(),
                desc: mySLides[2].getDesc(),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
        bottomSheet: slideIndex != 2 ? Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 1),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                onPressed: (){
                  controller.animateToPage(2, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 400), curve: Curves.linear);
                },
                splashColor: Colors.orange[200],
                child: Text(
                  "SKIP",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFFF57C00), fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    for (int i = 0; i < 3 ; i++) i == slideIndex ? _buildPageIndicator(true): _buildPageIndicator(false),
                  ],),
              ),
              FlatButton(
                onPressed: (){
                  print("this is slideIndex: $slideIndex");
                  controller.animateToPage(slideIndex + 1, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500), curve: Curves.linear);
                },
                splashColor: Colors.grey[200],
                child: Text(
                  "NEXT",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFFF57C00), fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ): InkWell(
          onTap: (){
            print("Get Started Now");
          },
          child: Container(
            height: Platform.isIOS ? 60 : 50,
            color: Colors.deepOrange,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Text(
              "GET STARTED NOW",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SlideTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final String imagePath, title, desc;

  SlideTile({this.imagePath, this.title, this.desc});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Image.asset(imagePath),
          SizedBox(
            height: 40,
          ),
          Text(title, textAlign: TextAlign.center,style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
              fontSize: 20
          ),),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          Text(desc, textAlign: TextAlign.center,style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
              fontSize: 14))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

My data.dart file

```
class SliderModel{

  String imageAssetPath;
  String title;
  String desc;

  SliderModel({this.imageAssetPath,this.title,this.desc});

  void setImageAssetPath(String getImageAssetPath){
    imageAssetPath = getImageAssetPath;
  }

  void setTitle(String getTitle){
    title = getTitle;
  }

  void setDesc(String getDesc){
    desc = getDesc;
  }

  String getImageAssetPath(){
    return imageAssetPath;
  }

  String getTitle(){
    return title;
  }

  String getDesc(){
    return desc;
  }

}


List<SliderModel> getSlides(){

  List<SliderModel> slides = new List<SliderModel>();
  SliderModel sliderModel = new SliderModel();

  //1
  sliderModel.setDesc("Discover Restaurants offering the best fast food food near you on Foodwa");
  sliderModel.setTitle("Search");
  sliderModel.setImageAssetPath("assets/images/illustration.png");
  slides.add(sliderModel);

  sliderModel = new SliderModel();

  //2
  sliderModel.setDesc("Our veggie plan is filled with delicious seasonal vegetables, whole grains, beautiful cheeses and vegetarian proteins");
  sliderModel.setTitle("Order");
  sliderModel.setImageAssetPath("assets/images/illustration2.png");
  slides.add(sliderModel);

  sliderModel = new SliderModel();

  //3
  sliderModel.setDesc("Food delivery or pickup from local restaurants, Explore restaurants that deliver near you.");
  sliderModel.setTitle("Eat");
  sliderModel.setImageAssetPath("assets/images/illustration3.png");
  slides.add(sliderModel);

  sliderModel = new SliderModel();

  return slides;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change `accentColor` in your `MaterialApp` of main.dart as,

```
return MaterialApp(
    theme: ThemeData(
        accentColor: Colors.red,
    ),
    home: MyApp(),
);
```

Or you can wrap your `PageView` with `Theme` as below,

```
Theme(
    data: ThemeData(
        accentColor: Colors.red,
    ),
    child: PageView(
        ...
    ),
),
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the question was asked years back, Now the accentColor is deprecated.
So, you can use the below code:

```
Theme(
      data: ThemeData(
      colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch().copyWith(secondary: Colors.deepPurple),
     ),
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try With this

```
 void main() {
      runApp(MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData(
          accentColor: Colors.orange
        ),
        home: MyApp(),
      ));
    }
```